# pie chart animation with arbitrary areas (with progress) without flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, pie-chart

I am trying to animate a pie chart
this is not the mouse-over and piece of the pie chart will pop up, so please be patient with what i have say

info:
1. there will only be two categories in the pie chart, right or wrong answers, thus only two colors displayed, very simple.
2. the area of each category (right or wrong) is NOT constant, it can be changed all the time, meaning, sometimes right can be 45%, and wrong can be 55%, the other case can be 35% and 65%
so i want the pie chart to shown clock-wise, displaying the right answer first and then the wrong proprotionally
so an example of that would be any pie chart in this link http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#pie-and-doughnut
(it is counter-clock-wiser in the link...)

so how can i archive that using only css/jquery? if not, using html 5? anything that don't require flash i guess.
is there an example of the animation with example code?

again, this is not moving a piece/portion of the pie chart out....

please see the link as what i meant..

Answer (score 0):

I have tried several Javascript chart libraries and I there is one that, from my point of view, is among the rest: [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)

Among other features, you can create awesome **pie charts** that will do what you want.  There are many examples out there about how to create those charts, and this one here: [HighCharts Pie Example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic) is the one you want to take a look at as a starting point.

Highcharts is build in pure Javascript and therefore doesn't require Flash at all.  The code would look something like this above, but **notice** that the data is statically written in the example, so depending on where/how are you getting the data, you will have to change that.

```
$(function () {
    var chart;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

            chart: {

                renderTo: 'container',

                plotBackgroundColor: null,

                plotBorderWidth: null,

                plotShadow: false

            },

            title: {

                text: 'Right or Wrong? That's the question'

            },

            tooltip: {

                formatter: function() {

                    return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';

                }

            },

            plotOptions: {

                pie: {

                    allowPointSelect: true,

                    cursor: 'pointer',

                    dataLabels: {

                        enabled: true,

                        color: '#000000',

                        connectorColor: '#000000',

                        formatter: function() {

                            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';

                        }

                    }

                }

            },

            series: [{

                type: 'pie',

                name: 'Right/Wrong',

                data: [

                    ['Right',   45.0],

                    ['Wrong',       26.8],


                ]

            }]

        });

    });


});​
```

Comment: do you know how they archive the effect? so it is purely css and js?

Comment: i like your link...but i am trying to make the use of library as last resort....my animation case is very simple...dont wanna bloat the program i am working on

Comment: Take a look at this then: http://www.elated.com/articles/snazzy-animated-pie-chart-html5-jquery/